# How can calculate the length and angle of the hypotenuse of a rectangle?

Tags: java, math

Given the length of the sides (height width) of a rectangle, I want to calculate the degrees of the hypotenuse going from one corner to another, as well as it's length (pythagorean theorem). How can I write this in java without "manually implementing the algorithms", having trouble finding the methods I'm looking for?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Have you thought about what formula you could use to produce that result?

Comment: use actual math? `arctan(height / width)`?

Comment: It can certainly be done _without_ `commons-math`, if that helps

Comment: @nvioli to calculate the length it's the pythagorean theorem methods, I haven't looked up calculating the angle of the hypotenuse yet. I've been method hunting, or  even package hunting, don't see anything related to that though.

Comment: @khelwood all math can be done with any computer (save these fancy new fuzzy math processors) given enough time. not helpful

Comment: Does this help? https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-finding-angle-right-triangle.html

Comment: I didn't say without a computer. I said without `commons-math`. You don't need to pull in an apache library to do basic geometry. See [Math.atan](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan-double-) and [Math.atan2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2-double-double-)

Comment: @khelwood alright, I've rephrased the question because I didn't even think about looking at the `Math` class.

Comment: It's worth noting this is the second time in 6 years I've needed an actual math algorithm of some kind beyond basic algebra (where I'm using algebra to mean x + y) I haven't used Trig/Geometry since high school.

Comment: I'm kind of of the opinion that in most cases there is a library better written, and better tested than anything I would write myself, in this case I had not considered that it would be in core java, so I looked for an external math library. Also I find some of these methods named in a way I wouldn't have looked for (but that's a familiarity issue).

Answer (score 2):

Given width `w` and height `h`, the length of the diagonal is given by

```
Math.sqrt(w*w+h*h) // pythagoras
```

Or you can use [`Math.hypot(w,h)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot-double-double-) to do this for you.

The angle of the diagonal can be calculated by

```
Math.atan(h/w) // arc tan in radians
```

You could also use the alternative arc tan function, [`atan2`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2-double-double-), but that only matters if you need the result to be returned in a particular range.

To convert from radians to degrees, you can use [`Math.toDegrees`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees-double-).

Comment: wouldn't you want `hypot` for the hypotenuse? same thing basically

Comment: Apparently so. I had not previously been aware of `hypot`. Thanks.

Comment: I just noticed it once you pointed out the `Math` class which I've not previously needed

Comment: also looks like there's an `atan2( y, x ) ` which does the division

Comment: You should really always use `atan2`. `atan(h/w)` will fail or give highly inaccurate results if `w` is small.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.function.Atan atan = org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.function.Atan();
double angle = atan.value(height/width);
org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.function.Sqrt sqrt = org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.function.Sqrt();
double length = sqrt.value(height*height+width*width);
```

Comment: @xenoterracide but you said using commons-math, then you edited your question. I just answered your original question, right?

Comment: yeah basically, I don't think it's bad to know how to do both, I'll accept an answer later in the day (I like to allow some time for upvoting to occur since people don't tend to read questions with accepted answers)